# Android NFC(Near field communication)

Tags: android, nfc

I need some kind of connection, to receive a value for an Android smartphone when standing infront a door. It can be done by using NFC tag. But it can only be used for very short distance(4cm). Anyone who have a solution for this???

Comment: Your question is not clear....be clear and specific.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the short distance? No.
It's called **Near** Field Communication for this exact reason. It only works for very short (near) distances.

Answer (score 0):

What about Bluetooth. The normal distance for phones if about 10 meters. You could create your own bluetooth server (there are many small boards for that) that would authenticate your mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

**As per Docs,**

Near Field Communication (NFC) is a set of short-range wireless technologies, typically requiring a `distance of 4cm or less` to initiate a connection. NFC allows you to share small payloads of data between an NFC tag and an Android-powered device, or between two Android-powered devices.

**So you can't with NFC...**

**Try [Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) or [Wifi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)..**